# Creating Instance Overwrites Class Object

Tags: python

I have a *Parent* and multiple *Children* classes. Each *Child* class comes with an empty *template* containing information about the structure of the class.

The Parent class contains a method `Parent.overwrite_key`: basically what it does is overwriting a given key from a `dict`. The method is recursive such that for nested dictionaries one can set the argument `key` to be a list and the method will go through the nested structure.

The `Parent.__init__` method is created such that in Children one can pass arguments to populate the template, e.g.

```
Children(Beta='hello', Alpha__field1__content = 'Something')
```

where I use the double underscore to separate fields.

## Code

Here is my code

```
class Parent(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.data = self.template.copy()
        for key,val in kwargs.items():
            key=key.split('__')
            Parent.overwrite_key(dic = self.data, key=key, val=val)

    @staticmethod
    def overwrite_key(dic, key, val, num=0):
        tmp_dic = dic
        if isinstance(key, list) and len(key) > 1:
            tmp_dic = tmp_dic[key[0]]
            if isinstance(tmp_dic, list):
                tmp_dic = tmp_dic[0]
            key = key[1:]
            Parent.overwrite_key(tmp_dic, key, val)
        elif isinstance(key, list) and len(key) is 1:
            key = key[0]
            tmp_dic[key] = val
            return
        elif isinstance(key, str):
            tmp_dic[key] = val
            return

class Child(Parent):

    template = {
      "Alpha": [
        {
          "field1": {
            "content": "",
            "source": ""
          }
        }
      ],
      "Beta": "",
      "Gamma": [
        ""
      ]
    }
```

## Problem

My issue is that when defining an instance of Children with some input parameters, then that seems to overwrite `Children.template`. See:

```
print(Child.template)
c = Child(Alpha__field1__content = 'Something')
print(c.data)
print(Child.template) 
# returns the following
{'Alpha': [{'field1': {'content': '', 'source': ''}}], 'Gamma': [''], 'Beta': ''}
{'Alpha': [{'field1': {'content': 'Something', 'source': ''}}], 'Gamma': [''], 'Beta': ''}
{'Alpha': [{'field1': {'content': 'Something', 'source': ''}}], 'Gamma': [''], 'Beta': ''}
```

Comment: Yes, because you call `Parent.overwrite_key(dic = self.data, key=key, val=val)` in the constructor, so creating an instance will call that.

Comment: Note, `self.data = self.template.copy()` makes a *shallow* copy of your template. Your `overwrite_key` func then *modifies the objects in this shallow copy in-place*, but those objects are the same objects in the original template. You can try doing a `copy.deepcopy`

Comment: `self.template.copy()` is a shallow copy. (These kinds of "copy a template object" approaches get very awkward in languages where copying isn't a core operation. They work better in something like C++. In languages like Python, reconstructing an object from scratch tends to work better.)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see, thanks. I thought `Parent.overwrite_key(...)` would merely overwrite `self.data` and not `self.template`. I will give it a try with `copy.deepcopy`.